# Modify string based on length?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my database, I have one column `zip` which includes all the US zipcodes as strings.

The issue I have is that the zipcodes starting with `0` are not considered as a 5-digit number (it's a string) and thus only have 4 digits.

Is there a way to replace those zipcodes having a length of 4 by adding a `0` in front of them? For example:

`1001` => `01001`

`10134` => not modified

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, strings are joined with the [`||` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop).
To restrict a query to a subset of records, use the [WHERE clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

```sql
UPDATE WhateverTheTableIsCalled
SET zip = '0' || zip
WHERE length(zip) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That query doesn't seem to change the values in the zip column, still show 4 digits instead of 4 :(

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(zip) FROM SuperSecretTableName`?